# How can I add user inputted values to my chart.js line graph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I'm trying to add a new X and y value to my Chart.js line graph but keep getting an error. I've tried so many different ways but can't seem to update dynamically from the user input . Is this possible? What am I missing?

I'm trying to add the new user data at the end of the chart. The X axis will be a date eventually.

```js
$('#update').click(function() {

  var xValue = $('#xValue').val;
  var yValue = $('#yValue').val;

  myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(xValue, yValue);
  myChart.update();
});


var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: "Body Fat % Progress",
      data: [{
          x: 1,
          y: 1
        },
        {
          x: 2,
          y: 2
        },
        {
          x: 3,
          y: 5
        },
        {
          x: 4,
          y: 0
        },
        {
          x: 5,
          y: 2
        },


      ],
      backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'],
      borderColor: ['rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)'],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },

  options: {
    legend: {
      labels: {
        // This more specific font property overrides the global property
        fontColor: 'white'
      }
    },

    scales: {

      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          displayFormats: {
            quarter: 'MMM D'
          }
        },
        display: true,
        gridLines: {

          display: true,
          color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)',


        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Date',
          fontColor: 'white'
        },
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: 'false',
          fontColor: 'white'
        }
      }],

      yAxes: [{
        display: true,
        color: 'white',
        gridLines: {
          display: true,
          color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)'
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Body Fat %',
          fontColor: 'white'
        },
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          fontColor: 'white'
        }
      }]

    },

    showAllTooltips: true,

    tooltips: {

      custom: function(tooltip) {
        if (!tooltip) return;

        // disable displaying the color box;
        tooltip.displayColors = false;
      },

      callbacks: {
        // use label callback to return the desired label
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          return tooltipItem.yLabel + '%';
        },
        title: function(tooltipItem, dat) {
          return 'Body Fat:';
        }

      }

    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="chart-container">

  <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

</div>

<input type="number" name="xValue" placeholder="X Value" id="xValue" />
<input type="number" name="yValue" placeholder="Y Value" id="YValue" />
<input type="submit" id="update" value="Update" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a few things:

1. You have a typo in the html code. You have `id="YValue"` instead of `id="yValue"`.
2. You put `.val` and it should be `.val()`.
3. `xValue` and `yValue` vars have to be numbers, not strings.
4. When you add the new data to the dataset, it has to be an object.

Putting Everything together...

**HTML**:

```
<div class="chart-container">
  <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>

<input type="number" name="xValue" placeholder="X Value" id="xValue" />
<input type="number" name="yValue" placeholder="Y Value" id="yValue" />
<input type="submit" id="update" value="Update" />
```

**JQUERY**:

```
$('#update').click(function() {

    var xValue = parseFloat($('#xValue').val());
    var yValue = parseFloat($('#yValue').val());

    myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push({ x: xValue, y: yValue });
    myChart.update();
});
```

Here you have a fiddle example... https://fiddle.jshell.net/rigobauer/ztsafu8w/

Comment: Thanks for the save @A.Iglesias, too much caffein and not enough sleep for me!

Comment: My pleasure! Have a nice day and happy coding!